# React Native download file from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want my react app to be able to download (for example) PDF files. But these PDF files should only be downloaded through my react app. If I google around for downloading files with react native all I get is stuff like react-native-fetch-blob and the request looks like this:

```
    .fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file/example.pdf', {
```

(The example above is part of a bigger piece of code.)

Now if you would visit http://www.example.com/file/example.pdf in your browser you will see the PDF file but I don't want that. I want to make it so that the PDF file can only be downloaded through the app and nowhere else.

How would I go about making a system like this?

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: You can secure your file by uploading it to `amazon-s3` or `firebase`, and request it using your private token.

Comment: You need to implement an authentication method so only authenticated requests can access the file.

Comment: @r3zaxd1 how would I go about doing that, sorry I am new to all of this.